# Read through OracleDataReader.Read()

Tags: c#, database

I want to collect a string from the database.
The following code i have:

[image]

ExecuteQry method:
[image]

[image]

"odr" isn't null, but he doesn't get through the "if" statement (odr.Read()).
I don't know why, hope someone can help me :)

Thanks

Comment: It looks like that no data were found in the database for a given _spoorNr_. Did you check this possibility? Besides, could you show us source code of `Database.ExecuteQry `method?

Comment: Check edit. In the database "SpoorNr" 56 exists

Comment: PLEASE don't post code as images, paste it as code, just indent it 4 spaces and it'll get marked as code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `new OracleParameter("spoorNr", spoorNr)` instead of `new OracleParameter(":spoorNr", spoorNr)` The only difference is lack of `:` symbol. The query remains as it is.